# Attribute :value binding in select tag doesn't update inside Vue 3 component template (Composition API)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-composition-api

I have a drop down menu where options are enumerated and shuffled, so that the selected option becomes the first. This script is working as intended:

```html
<div id="main">
  <sub-select :subs="data" @comp-update="onShufflePaths($event)"></sub-select>
</div>
```

. .

```js
 const ui = {
   setup() {
    
    let data = ref('first_second_thrid');
    
    const onShufflePaths = (ind) => {
        let subs = data.value.match(/[^_]+/g);
        const main = subs.splice(ind, 1)[0];
        data.value = [main, ...subs].join('_');
    }
        
     return {
       data, onShufflePaths, 
     };
   },
 };

 const vueApp = createApp(ui);
 
vueApp.component('sub-select', {
  props: ['subs'],
  emits: ['comp-update'],
  setup(props, { emit }) {
  
        let subs = computed(() => props.subs.match(/[^_]+/g));
    
    let subpath = computed(() => '0: ' + subs.value[0]);
    
    function onChange(evt) {
        emit('comp-update', evt.slice(0,1));                      
    } 
    
    return { subs, subpath, onChange };
  },
  template: `
  <select :value="subpath" @change="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option v-for="(v,k) in subs">{{k}}: {{v}}</option>
  </select> {{subpath}}`
});
 
 vueApp.mount('#main');
```

The problem is, if I delete {{subpath}} from the template, the drop down menu comes up with no options selected by default. It looks like :value="subpath" by itself is not enough to update subpath variable when props update, if it's not explicitly mentioned in the template.

How can I make it work?

Basically, I need the first option always to be selected by default.

Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/tfoller/uy7k1hvr/26/

Answer (score 1):

So, it looks like it might be a bug in the library.

**Solution 1:**

wrap select tag in the template in another tag, like this (so it's not the lonely root element in the template):

```js
template: `
  <div><select :value="subpath" @change="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option v-for="(v,k) in subs">{{k}}: {{v}}</option>
  </select></div>`
```

**Solution 2:**

Write a getter/setter to subpath variable, so component definition is as follows:

```js
vueApp.component('sub-select', {
  props: ['subs'],
  emits: ['comp-update'],
  setup(props, { emit }) {
  
        let subs = computed(() => props.subs.match(/[^_]+/g));
    
    let subpath = computed({
      get: () => '0: ' + subs.value[0],
      
      set (value) {
        emit('comp-update', value.slice(0,1))
      }
    });
    
    return { subs, subpath };
  },
  template: `
  <select v-model="subpath">
    <option v-for="(v,k) in subs">{{k}}: {{v}}</option>
  </select>`
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For having the first option selected by default you need to point to the index 0.

Here your index is the `k` from **v-for**

```
<option v-for="(v,k) in subs" :selected="k === 0">{{k}}: {{v}}</option>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no `v-model` in select, I think that is the main issue. Other is its not clear what you what to do.

please refer the following code and check if it satisfy your need.

```js
    // app.vue
    <template>
      <sub-select v-model="value" :options="options" />
      {{ value }}
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import { ref } from "vue";
    import subSelect from "./components/subSelect.vue";
    
    export default {
      name: "App",
      components: {
        subSelect,
      },
      setup() {
        const value = ref(null);
        const options = ref(["one", "two", "three"]);
    
        return { value, options };
      },
    };
    </script>
```

see that I have used `v-model` to bind the value to `sub-select` component.

the `sub-select` component as follows

```js
// subSelect.vue
<template>
  <select v-model="compValue">
    <template v-for="(option, index) in compOptions" :key="index">
      <option :value="option">{{ index }}: {{ option }}</option>
    </template>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
import { computed } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "subSelect",
  props: ["modelValue", "options"],
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    // if value is null then update it to be first option.
    if (props.modelValue === null) {
      emit("update:modelValue", props.options[0]);
    }

    const compValue = computed({
      get: () => props.modelValue,
      set: (v) => emit("update:modelValue", v),
    });
   
    // return selected option first in list/Array.
    const compOptions = computed(() => {
      const selected = props.options.filter((o) => o === compValue.value);
      const notSelected = props.options.filter((o) => o !== compValue.value);
      return [...selected, ...notSelected];
    });

    return { compValue, compOptions };
  },
};
</script>
```

in `sub-select` component i am checking first if `modelValue` is `null` and if so set value to be first option.

and also providing `compOptions` in such sequence that selected options will always be first in list of selection options.

so it satisfies

1. The first option always to be selected by default.
2. Selected option will always be first in list of options.

check the code working at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-hugle-mfl9z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

## edit

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1x8t06ay/3/) as per request

---

also i suspect that you need options as underscore separated string for that please refer [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) for converting it to array and [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) for joining array back to string.
if this is the case please comment so I can update my answer. It should be possible by setting watcher on `compOptions` and emitting separate event to parent, but I don't think its a good idea!

Comment: @user1481126 your select element must be bind with a single `ref` and options should be different. but seems like you are changing the list as per selection without binding value of selection `subpath` has no setter. Also length of code is subjective. it is what it is to fullfill the requirement. May be it can reduced a little, but you have to work for that. The example here is for community to understand easily. Again **it is more important that a code is human understandable rather than its length**